# Do you have to "Expose an API" in Microsoft Entra ID if your API doesn't use MS Graph? Is Validation enough?

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, token

Given the scenario below, I don't understand why I need to add a scope under the "Expose an API" section of a application registration in Microsoft Entra ID.

1. Client logs in to frontend SPA using Microsoft Entra ID and is provided a bearer token.
2. Client calls my backend API and provides bearer token.
3. Backend API validates the token and confirms user has a specific role by decoding the JWT.
4. Backend API connects to MS SQL database to retrieve data and sends it back to client.

In this scenario, my backend does not need to access MS Graph directly. I just want the API to be protected via the validation of the bearer token.

However, all the instructions I find, include creating a API scope and granting application permissions to specific roles. Isn't this only necessary if your backend API needs to request MS Graph resources directly?

Comment: As you are making use of two applications to authenticate to SQL hence you need to expose an API in the BackEnd application and grant API permissions for the BackEnd application and the API to call the SQL in the ClientApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply that you don't necessarily need to expose an API via the Azure app registration if you don't need to. If your application just needs the user to be logged in and has no special/specific API scopes (permissions) that need to be defined you don't need to add a custom API scope. Just  validate the access token provided after login and perform the necessary API actions.

If, however, you want/need to define various permission levels for your API's such as "Read Database", "Write Database", etc. then you can do so via the Azure Expose an API where you add your own custom scopes (permissions). The front-end application can then request those scopes so they are included into the access token which are then passed to your API, used to define what permissions the user or app has.

This is poorly explained is many, many articles as it seems to be assumed knowledge. If you are learning authentication it should be better spelled out.